# Verb classes confusion: unaccusative, unergative

Tags: syntax, terminology, morphology, unaccusative

I still have a confusion in relation to verb classes, I read somewhere here that 'unaccusatives' are types of unpaired unergatives, and somewhere else 'unaccusatives' are the opposite of 'unergatives'.. I get confused all the time about verb classes? Could someone explain them clearly please, or guide me to some references. thanks.

Comment: Your confusion is justified - I see people talking about languages like English having ergative verbs as well, with examples that looks identical to unaccusatives to me. "Unergative" in such a usage is just a normal intrasitive verb. "Unergative" is a more useful term in ergative languages though, where it is a marked construction, like unaccusatives can be in English.

Comment: thank you, what I meant by confusion is the different definitions authors keep giving to each concept. I read somewhere here that 'unaccusative' is a type of 'unergative' where this latter is unpaired. Somewhere I read they're totally different verb classes. Well share 'intransitivity' in common, but semantic valency is different where unaccusative's mono-argument isn't an agent. Is there any book or article dealing just with verb classes? I'm quite familiar with 'the syntax of verbs' by Koopman, but no thorough discussion was given there. thank you.